# remove all tags, after given tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this html

```
<div>
    <p></p>
    <!-- here may be several tags, may be none -->
</div>
```

I want at  click on document, remove all tags, which may be will after `<p>` tag, (after `<p>` tag may be several and may be none tags), please tell, how make this?

```
$(document).on("click", function () {
    // ???
})
```

Comment: `$("div p:first").nextAll().remove();`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$(document).on("click", function () {
    $('div > p').nextAll().remove();
})
```

Comment: I think the better selector would be $('div>p')

Comment: You're right. Updated my code. Though I'd use ids and classes

Comment: yes giving proper ids and classes are priceless, but I have found alot of the time you get some plugin or something that you are forced to work with because of the limitations of the layout.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [`.nextAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/) method:

```
$(document).on("click", function () {
  $('div>p').nextAll().remove();
})
```

I suggest naming your specific element with class or id .